# How to install a new font in TexWorks?

Tags: fonts

I'm using TexWork to write my documents. For one document I use a template that requires the font Frutiger. I have the font but I'm not able to install it. So anybody knows where to find a guide how to install a font?

I'm using pdfLaTeX and from the font I have *.map file.

Comment: @roflcopter I removed the `texworks` tag: Your question doesn't seem to be specific to texworks.

Comment: It's difficult to give an answer. You must describe the font : truetype, OTF or PS type 1,etc. Do you have the files .tfm, .map,etc. Do you work with pdflatex or latex or XeTeX. We need all these information to give a correct answer.

Comment: TeXWorks is an editor, and installation questions depend on operating system and distribution (e.g., TeXLive).

Comment: @Altermundus Matthew Leingang Ok I try to update all these information in my question.

Comment: The template is most likely for XeTeX + fontspec. If that is the case, you can just install it on your system, and fontspec will automagically find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing fonts is basically black magic. The [font installation guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.pdf) is helpful, but it's still no walk in the park.

If you really need to use a specific font, XeTeX or LuaTeX might be a better option.

Comment: It's probably not black magic, and I'm sure many of the power users in this community can do it with aplomb. But I agree with the sentiment.  When I wanted to start using a larger set of fonts, I switched to XeTeX.

Comment: Thanks, It took my some hours but now it is finally working!

Comment: This link is broken now. Can it be fixed?

Comment: @LeeWhite The link should be fixed now. Although, in fairness, you could have just searched for "font installation guide latex" yourself...